# Is python ggplot still being developed?

Tags: python, plot, graphing, python-ggplot

Python ggplot is great, but missing many customization options.

The commit history on github for the past year does not look very promising...

Does anyone know if it is still being developed?

Comment: There is https://github.com/has2k1/ggplot/tree/rewrite/ggplot and https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/pull/360 -> There is something coming but the rewrite is curently stuck in a "incomplete rewrite" stage. :-(

Comment: @JanSchulz Thanks, that's good to know.

Comment: I'm fairly new at this, so I'd like to know why was this question marked down? There is nothing about this on their website and no notice of the rewrite on the repo readme and there was no response to my issue requests on github, so I wasn't sure whether the project was being actively developed.

Comment: @ColinAnthony, it's a time-sensitive question about an off-site resource, with any answer liable to become incorrect over time; hardly a good fit for a canonical knowledgebase (which SO exists to build). We explicitly disallow questions requesting suggestions of off-site resources for similar reasons; the reasons against allowing those apply to this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They are currently doing a major rewrite.